# FTPS with GitHub Actions output SSL_connect: wrong version number

Tags: github-actions, ftps, lftp

I am trying to build a GitHub Action that, upon pushing website content on a private repository, deploys the content to a remote web hosting server, through FTP over SSL (the only option available)

The deployment is done with [lftp](https://lftp.yar.ru/), as follows:

```sh
lftp \
--debug \
-u ${INPUT_USER}, ${INPUT_PASSWORD}\
${INPUT_FTP_SERVER} \
-e "set ftp:ssl-force true; set ssl:check-hostname false; set ftp:nop-interval 2; set ftp:passive-mode false; set net:max-retries 1; set net:timeout 20; set dns:max-retries 8; set dns:fatal-timeout 10; mirror --reverse ${INPUT_LOCAL_FOLDER} ${INPUT_REMOTE_FOLDER}"
```

However, when running the docker container I get the following error:

```
Libraries used: Readline 8.1
---- Resolving host address...
---- IPv6 is not supported or configured
---- 1 address found: xx.yy.www.zzz
---- Connecting to ftp.aaa.bbb (xx.yy.www.zzz) port pp
**** SSL_connect: wrong version number
---- Closing control socket
```

I already tested the docker image and the command locally with success, so the problem is probably related to some GitHub configuration that I am not able to figure out.

Does anyone know what's happening?